# Use FabricJS with Windows8 app?

Tags: javascript, html, winjs, fabricjs

Has anyone had success building a windows 8 app with Fabric JS?

I am trying to port a site I made into an app, but keep getting errors of stuff in the fabric.js file being undefined.

Would fabric even work on this? My site doesn't work on IE...

Let me know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using fabricJS library in Win8 app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328022/using-fabricjs-library-in-win8-app)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you have to modify fabric.js source code to make it work.

as known that win8 is mouse/touch both supported OS, so you have to change the 'fabric.isTouchSupported' related events, touch events and mouse events, as fabric.isTouchSupported is true on win8, the original source code will not register events for mouse, so you can's select/move/rotate object, but if you make it register events.

for IE, I think you should use IE8+. check your js code.

and you could download excanvas.js from fabric source code site.
`<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/excanvas.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->`