# Using fabricJS library in Win8 app?

Tags: windows-8, fabricjs

Has anyone successfully used FabricJS (or other similar libraries) in developing Windows 8 apps?
I am trying, but keep getting fatal errors thrown at me (mainly, variables in the fabric file being undefined).

I am trying to port a website I created using Fabric JS over, but I am wondering because the site does not work on IE.. so would it even work on Win8 native apps?

Comment: HTML5/JavaScript apps on Windows 8 do still use of the IE10 rendering and JavaScript engine, so I'd probably make sure it worked in IE10 as a web app before bringing to Windows 8.

Comment: Which variables are undefined? Feel free to [create an issue in a tracker](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues).